# how to fix this warning in reactjs "Warning: React does not recognize the `showLabel` prop on a DOM element." showing in console log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

[image]

### How to remove this Warning: React does not recognize the `showLabel` prop on a DOM element.

**Warning message showing on console log.**

> Warning: React does not recognize the `showLabel` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `showlabel` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

Comment: Without seeing your exact code, it's hard to say. I'd guess you're doing something like `<div showLabel={...} />` and showLabel doesn't exist on a native dom element (`div`). The error message is pretty helpful.

Comment: Can you show how your parent is providing the props? Here you have a good reference for search: https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html

Answer (score 11):

This error appears when a React component prop ends up being added as an attribute on a DOM element.

Typically this error will appear when passing props to a component that then uses the spread operator to pass them into another component. Consider a contrived example like this:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  return (<ChildComponent showLabel={true} />);
}

const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <div {...props}>blah blah blah</div>
  )
}
```

In this case the `showLabel` prop that you passed to `ChildComponent` ends up being rendered as an attribute on a `div` tag, which isn't allowed as indicated by the error message you're seeing.

Make sure any props that you're passing into a component are accounted for, and if necessary remove them or destructure and only pass the necessary props to the next component:

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  const { someLabel, ...rest } = props;
  return (
    <div {...rest}>blah blah blah</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: This is very true and nicely explained.
Cor, javascript is like sticking a hot needle into an open wound.